# Formula field based on future activity

Tags: salesforce

I want to create a calculated field that will calculate the date of the next activity of a certain type, associated with an opportunity. Specifically, an event with the customer.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom field, which will be updated in some way (DML, trigger, Workflow) together with your activity.
So your formula field will be calculated according to this activity. As example

```
IF(ISBLANK(Custom_Field__c), 'Pending...',  /*Some calculations with Custom_Field__C*/ ).
```

In this way your formula will show "Pending..." value until activity happens.